# Set margins programmatically to a tag Fragment

Tags: android, kotlin

Is it possible to set margins programmatically to a Tag Fragment in Android?.

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
    android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:layout_marginBottom="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:defaultNavHost="true"
    app:navGraph="@navigation/main_nav_graph" />
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

It would be better if you can use FrameLayout instead of Fragment Tag. Here is an example of that.

```
getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .add/replace(R.Id.your_frame_layout_id, new YourFragment())
            .commit();
```

Then you can get the layout params for the parent layout of your FrameLayout. For example, if your frame is inside RelativeLayout then get params for Relative layout.

```
 RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rlp = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)fl.getLayoutParams();
    rlp.setMargins(0,0,0,0); //Set your margins here 
    fl.setLayoutParams(rlp);
```

I wrote the answer in terms of java. If you are looking for kotlin then the approach might be similar.